# How to say something covers all the view up to the horizon line?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, idiom-requests

I am trying to say something (e.g. wheat field) is visible on whole photo, from observer point up to the horizon, expanded into both left and right directions. I am looking for some idiom or singular verb that can express that idea (as I can do it in Polish).

I wish it was describing universal property of the field, and not be bound to particular observer, that's why I discarded "cover all the view" from title.

On some online dictionaries I found "all the way up to the horizon" expression. Thus: "fields outstreched all the way up to the horizon".

I came up with "field extends/outstretches all over the horizon", but I am not sure whenever it is not bad copy of "all over the world" expression.

Also, I am not sure whenever any of these express the idea of fields being visible not only on the horizon, but on the whole view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An idiom which can help here is ***as far as the eye can see***.

> The wheat field stretches ***as far as the eye can see***.

TFD(idioms):

> **[as far as the eye can see](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+far+as+the+eye+can+see)**
>   Extending to the farthest possible point, as of that which one can see in the distance.
>   Sometimes used hyperbolically, humorously, or sarcastically.
>   I love
>   this part of the country. The green hills stretch out as far as the
>   eye can see.
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.
>
> **as far as the eye can/could ˈsee**
>   to the horizon: There was only sand as far as the eye could see.
>
> Farlex Partner Idioms Dictionary © Farlex 2017

Answer (score 3):

Because you are referring to a photo, you can say the field **fills the frame**:

> #### What is the Frame and Why Fill It?
>
> Here, the frame refers to the edges of your photograph or the edges of the viewfinder of your camera when you are shooting. The advice to fill the frame means to get in close, to make your subject a significant portion of the final photograph.
>   <sub>[Composition: Fill the Frame](http://www.boostyourphotography.com/2014/06/fill-the-frame.html)</sub>

This expression can be used to refer to something large (like a wheat field) or something small (like a single flower), as long as it fills most of the picture. This expression can also be used no matter if it's a photograph, drawing, or painting.